# SQL set WHERE statement with CASE puts an error with add operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause

In the following script, I want to set the WHERE statement only if the CASE is set.

```sql
DECLARE @cmdINSERT  varchar(8000);
declare @dowhere binary;
declare @date varchar(10);

set @dowhere = 1;
set @date = '14.03.2020';

set @cmdINSERT = 
'SELECT *
  FROM [TABLE]
    WHERE [Changed At] >= 
        CASE WHEN ' + @dowhere + '
            when 1 THEN ''' + @date + '''
            ELSE [Changed At]
        end;'

EXEC(@cmdINSERT)
```

But I am getting the error:

> The data types varchar and binary are incompatible in the add operator

Comment: `CASE WHEN 1 WHEN 1 THEN..`?

Comment: `binary` is not the correct datatype here anyway. I guess you wanted `bit` - though this doesn't resolve all your issues

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL here, when there is nothing dynamic about it?

Comment: @Larnu thanks. it is dynamic, I just simplified it with values as example.

Comment: Then you have overly simplfied the problem, @Giovanni19. This appears to be wide open to injection, and the SQL we have should **not** be dynamic.

Comment: Hmm - you declared your string variable as `@cmdINSERT` yet you attempt to generate a SELECT query. Do you see how your code is more difficult to understand when your names do not match the usage? If you simply want to ignore `@date` when `@dowhere` is zero, then just test for it using an IF stmt - don't overcomplicate the logic. Erland discusses [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) in great detail which should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have complicated the solution. Why you do not try this?

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table]
WHERE @dowhere = 0
      OR [Changed At] >= @date;
```

However it would be better if you change the data type of `@dowhere` to BIT instead of `BINARY`

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're overly complicating the matter. You don't need a dynamic statement here, nor do you need 2 parameters. Use a single parameter, and pass the value `NULL` if you don't want to consider it. This is what is known as a "catch up" or "kitchen sink" query:

```sql
DECLARE @Date date = '20200314'; --Notice it is NOT a varchar

SELECT {Your Columns} --Replace this with a list of your columns
FROM dbo.YourTable --Replace this with your actual schema and table
WHERE [Changed At] >= @Date --Ideally, don't use names that must be delimit Identified
   OR @Date IS NULL
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

The `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is there to stop caching of the wrong plan, as if `@Date` has a value of `NULL` a full table scan will be required, however, if not then (depending on your indexes) one may not be required, which could be far faster. As the query is incredibly simple, the expense of regenerating query plan will be negligible, and likely <=1ms in cost.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is silly.  Get rid of the `case` in the `where` altogether if no filtering is desired:

```
set @cmdINSERT = '
SELECT *
FROM [TABLE]
[where]';

SET @cmdInsert = REPLACE(@cmdInsert,
                         '[where]',
                         (CASE WHEN @dowwhere = 1
                               THEN 'WHERE [Changed At] = @date'
                               ELSE ''
                          END)
                         );
exec sp_executesql @cmdInsert, N'@date date', @date=@date;
```

Note that this also *properly* passes in the date as a parameter rather than munging the query string.  If the date parameter is not used, that is fine:  SQL Server just ignores parameters that are not used.